# Easy regular expression- please correct

Tags: regex, perl

I have `AUD0.7195`.
I want to mach `AUD` in `$1` and `0.7195`in `$2`.
The amount may vary. It can be positive integer.
I have tried with:

```
 /([A-Z]{3})(\d{+}\.?\d*)/ms;
```

But it matches nothing. What is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d{+}` doesn't make sense and should be `\d+`

Answer (score 2):

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Use this.Yours does not work as `\d{+}` does not act as quantifier.

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try this:

```
my $string = "AUD0.7195";
print "$1\t$2.......\n", if($string=~m/^([\w]{3})([0-9\-\.]*)$/g);
```